Trace class condition equivalence
Operators $A$ and $B$ on an infinite Hilbert space are bounded and invertible. I am trying to prove  a conjecture for $A,B$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{i}
(A-I)(B-I),(B-I)(A-I) \in \mathcal{L}_1, 
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}_1$ is a trace-class ideal.
I have managed to prove the conjecture for $A,B$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{ii}
AB-I \in \mathcal{L}_1 \quad \mathrm{or/and} \quad  BA-I \in \mathcal{L}_1. 
\end{equation}
Both conditions $(i)$ and $(ii)$ seem similar, but which one is more general? Are there any operators, that satisfy $(ii)$ but not $(i)$? Are they under any circumstances equivalent?
Edit: sorry, forgot to add the additional constraints, namely $[A,B] \in \mathcal{L}_1$, but also $[A,B] \neq 0$.

This appears straightforward if I did not miss the point: For $A=2\cdot\operatorname{id}$ and $B=A^{-1}=0.5\cdot\operatorname{id}$, condition $(ii)$ is fulfilled, but $(i)$ is not.

Thanks for the insight about identities. I edited my question. I was looking for a non-trivial example so in my mind I was ignoring A or B being identity (or multiples).

The example of @Hanno can be modified in order to meet the assumptions. Let $S$ and $T$ be one dimensional non commuting operators such that $\|S\|,\|T\|<{1\over 2}.$ The operators $A={1\over 2}(I+S)$ and $B=2(I+T)$ are invertible and satisfy (ii). Moreover $$ [A,B]=[S,T]\in \cal{L}_1 $$ The operators $I-A={1\over 2}I-{1\over 2}S$ and $I-B=-I-2T$ are invertible and so are their products $(I-A)(I-B)$ and $(I-B)(I-A).$ Hence (ii) is satisfied while (i) isn't.
Also (i) does not imply (ii). Indeed let $A=I+S$ and $B=2(I+T).$ Then $I-A\in \cal{L}_1,$ thus (i) holds. However neither condition of (ii) is  satisfied.
